# Group more UIImageViews in one UIImageView

Tags: ios

I was wondering if it was possible to group more UIImageViews in one single imageview. If for example I have 4 imageViews, and I want to animate them in the same exact way, can I group them into one, and animate that single image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not group several UIImageViews into one UIView? If the whole idea is to display several UIImages at the same time, I see no advantage in drawing them into one container.

Here is an example:

```
UIImageView *iv1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"]];
UIImageView *iv2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"]];
UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, iv1.frame.size.width + iv2.frame.size.width, MAX(iv1.frame.size.height,iv2.frame.size.height))];
[mainView addSubview:iv1];
iv2.frame = CGRectMake(iv1.frame.size.width, 0.0f, iv2.frame.size.width, iv2.frame.size.height);
[mainView addSubview:iv2];
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  Could you share how this could be done?